# What happened to 3D Action Effects in Cocos2d 3.0?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, xcode5

I cannot find the following in Cocos2d v3.0

CCTiledGrid3D
CCTiledGrid3DAction
CCGrid3D
CCGrid3DAction

Furthermore, the following code is outdated or invalid:

```
// IMPORTANT: Call this function at the very beginning, before running your 1st scene
// Create a depth buffer of 24 bits
// These means that openGL z-order will be taken into account
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] setDepthBufferFormat:kDepthBuffer16];
```

Answer (score 2):

Is this you are looking ? Check AppDelegate.m, there you can set opions

```
[self setupCocos2dWithOptions:@{
                                CCSetupDepthFormat: @GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8,
                            CCSetupPixelFormat: kEAGLColorFormatRGBA8
    }];
```